# React 16: access context from outside of function component

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm using React 16 and trying to use a React hook to access context.

```
const { locale } = React.useContext(LocaleContext);
```

This hook call is being done inside a Redux middleware. I then get the error 
`Invariant Violation: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.`

Is there any way for me to access context from outside of a functional component?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to use a hook outside a React component. If you really need to access the locale inside redux you can either keep an outside reference to it somewhere:

```
let globalLocale;

// inside a component
function MyComponent() {
  const {locale} = React.useContext(LocaleContext);
  globalLocale = locale;
}
```

Or you can add the locale in redux with an action (inside your LocaleContext e.g., whenever it changes):

```
// inside LocaleContextProvider somewhere, when locale updates 
dispatch({type: 'SET_LOCALE', payload: locale});
```

The you'll be able to access it in redux like any other value.